# how to run JAR file in emulator in eclipse configured for Samsung SDK

Tags: java-me, midlet

I need to run a jar file which is application for  for SAMSUNG mobiles. I have configured my eclipse with Latest samsung SDK for java. I also able to run a sample application on emulator. Now I have to run a JAR file in that emulator. Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below are the steps to run JAR file on Samsung emulator.

Prerequisites:
 1. You must have both JAR and JAD files.
 2. Download Samsung SDK from the link :http://innovator.samsungmobile.com/down/cnts/toolSDK.list.do?platformId=2

Step 1. Place Jad and Jar files at the same folder. 
Step 2. Run the below command from bin folder of Samsung SDK.
   D:\Samsung_SDK_120_Beta\bin>emulator -Xdescriptor:..\%folder%\LAWBook.jad -Xdevice:GT-S5230N